# Powershell : FileSystemWatcher for filename change

Tags: powershell, filenames, filesystemwatcher, file-rename

I tried using this code to monitor filename changes on our fileserver. But I only want to trigger the event when the extension changes.

Any suggentions?

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "E:\"
# $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $Name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path, $name"
            Add-content "E:\log.txt" -value $logline
          }

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: In the future I'd recommend adding the powershell tag to any question relating to powershell. There are a number of knowledgeable powershell users here and that will help them assist you quicker!

Answer (score 0):

Set the NotifyFilter property in the $watcher variable to FileName only.

```
$watcher.NotifyFilter = 'FileName'
```

Now the action will only trigger for file name changes.